# Error while setting OID using SNMP set

Tags: linux, snmp

I am trying to set a value to an OID using SNMP set from a Linux server.
I am able to set the OID sometimes while I am not able to set it other times and get an error.
This is the command I give for SNMP:

```
snmpset -v 2c -c priv 10.xxx.xxx.xxx 1.3.6.1.2.1.90.1.2.1.1.3.5.97.98.99.99.101.1.38 string '2'
```

and the error which I get is the following:

```
Error in packet.
Reason: noCreation (That table does not support row creation or that object can not ever be created)
Failed object: SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.90.1.2.1.1.3.5.97.98.99.99.101.1.38
```

It is totally random that the command is executed successfully or the error is given. Can anyone please tell why is this error shown? Any links can also be provided if there is a proper solution.

> EDITED

```
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.90.1.2.1.1.3.5.97.98.99.99.101.1.38 = No Such Instance currently exists at this OID
```

The above is the output of both snmpget and walk.

Comment: Can you add the output for snmpget (or snmpwalk) for your OID in each scenario?  Also is that actually a valid OID and how did you obtain it ?

Comment: yes it is a valid OID, it is actually a custom OID created using Expression MIB

Comment: Your edited question shows the GET result after a failed SNMP SET, I assume? Does the SNMP GET retrieve a valid value after the successful SET?

Comment: yes @k1eran it is fetching the correct result when SET is successful.